# Copy and paste queries/formulas from one column into a new column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a bunch of formulas in my column's cells. I want to make a duplicate column with the same queries/formulas, and if I ever make a change in one of the cells in the column, it applies to all the same cells on the same row in the other columns.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome. Please describe your research in preparing for this question. A couple of things to clarify: Are you familiar with the difference between absolute and/or relative cell references and how they work in formulas? What kind of formulas appear in the first column? Would you please provide a sample screenshot of your data layout and give an explanation, with examples for your statement _and if I ever make a change in one of the cells in the column, it applies to all the same cells on the same row in the other columns_. Lastly, please include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: You can try a script  to update the new column's cells each time there's a change in the original column.